# how to assign a value to a variable property within jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, variable-assignment

how can I assign a value to the 'extraParams' property of the following plugin 'defaults' object, from **outside** the plugin?

```
(function ($) {
jQuery.fn.jScroller = function (store, parameters) {
    var defaults = {
        //numberOfRowsToRetrieve: 10,
        onSuccessCallback: function (row, container) { },
        onErrorCallback: function (thrownError) { window.alert('An error occurred while trying to retrive data from store'); },
        onTimeOutCallback: function () { },
        timeOut: 3 * 1000,
        autoIncreaseTimeOut: 1000,
        retryOnTimeOut: false,
        loadingButtonText: 'Loading...',
        loadMoreButtonText: 'Load more',
        fullListText: 'There is no more items to show',
        routValues: null
```

I tried this, but leads to an error:

```
$.jScroller.defaults.extraParams = val;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 very simple plugins. Neither has any defaults set, yet both respond to options being passed into them. One uses `$.fn.plugin.defaults` to set the defaults, the other uses a local `var` as you have started. To a certain degree it is a matter of personal preference along with complexity of plugin as to which way you set defaults.

Note that options are being set externally on plugin #2 two different ways

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fCbm8/1

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.plugin_1 = function(options) {
        var defaults = {}; /* merge the options into defaults*/
        var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            if (opts.green) {
                $(this).css('background', 'green')
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
(function($) {
    $.fn.plugin_2 = function(options) { /* merge the options into defaults*/
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin_2.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            if (opts.big) {
                $(this).css('font-size', '30px')
            }
            if (opts.color) {
                $(this).css('color', 'white')
            }
        });
    }

    $.fn.plugin_2.defaults = {};

})(jQuery)


$(function() {
    $.fn.plugin_2.defaults.big = true;
    $('div').plugin_2({color:true}).plugin_1({green: true  })

})
```

Comment: tnks. by your ex' I see that I can assign values to Defaults from outside. why couldn't I in my code?

Comment: only if you set your code up as I did in plugin_2. The difference is that `var` is only accessible inside the function. Look at the `$.extend` of both of mine. They are different

Comment: yeah..is easy to write about $.extend but seeing the 2 methods side by side likely helped

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> For more complex and customizable plugins that provide many options, it's a best practice to have default settings that can get extended (using `$.extend`) when the plugin is invoked. So instead of calling a plugin with a large number of arguments, you can call it with one argument which is an object literal of the settings you would like to override.

```
  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {  

    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'location'         : 'top',
      'background-color' : 'blue'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {        

      // Tooltip plugin code here

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

In the example, the manual shows how you can call the plugin by passing extra parameters, overriding the default ones if you wish to (like `{location: left}`).

Comment: How does it know to replace values of 'location' and 'bakcground-color' which are within 'defaults', if you're not mention 'defaults' within 'extend' method? Is this code correct?

Comment: The code is taken from an example, it is not based on *your* code (sorry I am at workplace and cannot adapt it, no time), but should be easy to implement with your plugin.

Comment: I know it's not - it's a general question related to your example. May you read again?

Comment: Just change "tooltip" to you function, use $.extend on defaults. When you call the function you pass a settings object like `{extraParams: "etc." }`